# Maven errors to get a property from another pom

Tags: java, xml, maven, pom.xml, parent-pom

I have 3 pom.xml,
In one pom I have the profiles for test/prod.., depending on which one is active there are 2 folder it could be choose, the problem is when I update maven I get this error:

```
     on project projWeb: Execution default-war of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:3.2.2:war fai
led: basedir C:\Progetti\Proj\sviluppo\archicon\projWeb\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\jbossWeb\${current.jbossWeb} does not exist -
```

in the parent pom I have this: `C:\Progetti\Proj\sviluppo\proj\pom.xml`

```
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>it.sisal</groupId>
<artifactId>proj</artifactId>
<version>${appVersion}</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<name>Proj</name>
<modules>
    <module>projWeb</module>
    <module>projEAR</module>
</modules>
....
<profile>
            <id>test</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <environment.profile>test</environment.profile>
                <current.jbossWeb>securityOff</current.jbossWeb>
            </properties>
        </profile>
```

In my child pom.xml: `C:\Progetti\Proj\sviluppo\proj\projWeb\pom.xml`

```
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>it.sisal</groupId>
    <artifactId>projWeb</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.40-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Proj Web</name>

    <parent>
        <artifactId>proj</artifactId>
        <groupId>it.sisal</groupId>
        <version>${appVersion}</version>
    </parent>
 <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!--                    <warSourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/WebContent</warSourceDirectory> -->
                    <webXml>${current.webXml}</webXml>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                    <!--                    <warSourceExcludes>css/</warSourceExcludes> -->
                    <webResources>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>${jbossWeb.folder}/${current.jbossWeb}</directory>
                            <targetPath>WEB-INF</targetPath>
                        </resource>
                    </webResources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Even in Intellij I can see: [image]

Can Somebody could explain me why Can't I get the property and how could I solve it, please.

Comment: `C:\Progetti\Proj\sviluppo\proj\pom.xml` , where  is your `${appVersion}`

Comment: @life888888 thanks for the comment, it stored in properties in that pom.cml <appVersion>0.0.40-SNAPSHOT</appVersion>

Comment: Will your `test` profile be enabled forever? Because your property `current.jbossWeb` is defined in the test profile block, that is, **if the test profile is not enabled**, there should be no `current.jbossWeb` property set.

Comment: Hi, yes each profile has setted the property with value to securityOff or securityOn and I was trying with the test profile

Comment: Simply answer to this: `<version>${appVersion}</version>` that does not work. There is only one way to reach something alike via https://maven.apache.org/maven-ci-friendly.html (But most recent version really recommended.)